# Does Bootstrap create gutters inside custom directive elements?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

Using Bootstrap and Angular. I have a div inside a custom directive. Even when I set the child div width: 100%; it seems there are gutters on either side of the child div. I tried to adjust margin and padding of both parent element and child divs, including with negative numbers, without any change.

I want to force the div '.panel-content-wrapper' to fill the entire width of 'preview-panel' (a custom directive element)

html:

```
<preview-panel>

    <div class="panel-content-wrapper">

        <a href="{{panel.templateUrl}}">
        <div class="preview-left">
            <div class= "info-wrapper">
                <img ng-src="{{panel.iconUrl}}">
                <h3>{{panel.name}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>


        <div class="preview-right">
            <div class="essential-action">
                <button>{{panel.essentialAction}}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="preview-quicklook">
                <h5>Quicklook<h5>
                <p>{{panel.essentialInfo}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</preview-panel>
```

css:

```
preview-panel {
        height: 240px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #383838;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
        .panel-content-wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
            .preview-left{
                display: inline-block;
                height: 230px;
                width: 30%;
                border-radius:10px;
                background-color: #474747;
                border: 1px solid #2489cc;
                padding: 0;
            }

                .info-wrapper {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 50%;
                    transform: translateY(-50%);
                    overflow: hidden;
                    margin: auto;
                }

                    .info-wrapper img {
                        display: block;
                        margin: auto;
                    }


            .preview-right {
                display: inline-block;
                float: right;
                height: 100%;
                width: 70%;
                /*border: 2px solid blue;*/
                padding: 0;
                display: table;
            }

                .essential-action {
                    display: table-row;
                    height: 33.333%;

                }

                    .essential-action button {
                        position: relative;
                        top: 50%;
                        transform: translateY(-50%);
                    }

                .preview-quicklook {
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: #474747;
                    padding: 0;
                    display: table-row;
                    height: 66.666%;
                }
```

Comment: Inspect the `.panel-content-wrapper` using dev tools. You should see where the gutter (margin) come from. By default there should be no margin added by bootstrap on your custom css classes, so it must be some other css within your application.

Comment: have you tried `display: block;` on preview-panel?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to force the div to expand and fill its parent container using

```
.panel-content-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
            display: block;
```